# Корректный перевод design guidelines в контексте языка программирования

Tags: жаргон, переводы

Как наиболее близко к смыслу перевести на русский выражение design guidelines в контексте языков программирования?

Мультитран говорит как "Рекомендации по проектированию/принципы проектирования"? Это устоявшееся выражение в русском языке, получается?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, похоже, что это устоявшийся технический термин, применяющийся в архитектуре, инженерии и проч., см.:

> This work, which is to be undertaken by the lead design firm, consists of the development of the overall base **design guidelines** to be adopted by the specialist designers, which covers all aspects of construction, including architecture, structure, and mechanical and electrical systems.
>
> Эта работа, которую будет выполнять ведущая проектная фирма, включает **разработку общих базовых руководящих принципов проектирования**, подлежащих утверждению инженерами-проектировщиками по отдельным видам работ, которые охватывают все аспекты строительства, включая архитектурные, структурные и механические работы и электрические системы.
>
> Architectural **design guidelines** should be updated to reflect experience with completed portions of the project and shared among all the design teams.
>
> Следует внести изменения в **руководящие положения** об архитектурном облике с учетом проделанной работы по завершенным частям проекта и ознакомить с этими изменениями все группы проектировщиков.
> (https://context.reverso.net/)

Так что да, устоявшийся перевод.

Comment: Про архитектуру и инженерию в целом согласен - довольно точно передаёт смысл. Однако, что касается языков программирования... Не знаю, как-то слишком обще в этом контексте звучит, потому и спрашиваю.